# R parallel makeCluster() hangs infinitely on Mac

Tags: r, macos, parallel-processing, firewall, r-future

I came across some problem when I was trying to use `parallel` package in R on my Mac.

Here is how the parallel package works normally.

```
cl = makeCluster(2) # Using 2-core parallel as an example
# Your parallel code
stopCluster(cl)
```

When I ran this code, the `cl = makeCluster(2)` **hangs infinitely**. I was trying to solve it but failed. I also referred to some other posts. Several potential reasons includes not enough memory, installation error, etc. They do not seems to be the problem here, as I restarted sessions, reinstalled R, but the problem remained.

I guess the problem is about the permission when R tried to connect to cores. Here is what I found out. I used `future` package to see the specific process of connecting to cores. Attached are the code and its return.

```
cl <- future::makeClusterPSOCK(2, verbose = TRUE)
```

> Workers: [n = 2] ‘localhost’, ‘localhost’
>   Base port: 11303
>   Creating node 1 of 2 ...
>   - setting up node
>   Starting worker #1 on ‘localhost’: '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/Rscript' --default packages=datasets,utils,grDevices,graphics,stats,methods -e 'parallel:::.slaveRSOCK()' MASTER=localhost PORT=11303 OUT=/dev/null TIMEOUT=2592000 XDR=TRUE
>   Waiting for worker #1 on ‘localhost’ to connect back

The problem is the localhost never connects back ...

The following my the session info. I hope this helps.

> R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02).
>   Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit).
>   Running under: macOS High Sierra 10.13.6.
>
> Matrix products: default.
>   BLAS:        /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib.
>   LAPACK:     /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib
>
> locale:
>   [1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8
>
> attached base packages:
>   [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
>
> loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
>   [1] compiler_3.5.1   parallel_3.5.1   tools_3.5.1      listenv_0.7.0       codetools_0.2-15 digest_0.6.16
>   [7] globals_0.12.2   future_1.9.0

It's interesting that the same code works on my old Mac machine (same OS but the hardware is older). I have no idea what is happening here. Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Several potential reasons includes not enough memory, installation error, etc. They do not seems to be the problem here, as I restarted sessions, reinstalled R, but the problem remained.

Correct, those type of problems should not be involved here.  The calls you've shown use basic built-in functionalities of R (mostly from the 'parallel' package) and there's very little memory usage involved.

> I guess the problem is about the permission when R tried to connect to cores. [...]

Both `parallel:makeCluster(2)` and `future::makeClusterPSOCK(2)` launches workers (using the `parallel:::.slaveRSOCK()`) that are independent R sessions that run in the background.  The master session and these workers communicate via sockets.  So, yes, it could be that you have firewall issues preventing R from opening those ports.  (I don't know enough macOS to troubleshoot that)

By setting `outfile = NULL`, you will also get information on what happens on the workers' end. Here is what it should look like when it works:

```
> cl <- future::makeClusterPSOCK(1, outfile = NULL, verbose = TRUE)
Workers: [n = 1] ‘localhost’
Base port: 11306
Creating node 1 of 1 ...
- setting up node
Starting worker #1 on ‘localhost’: '/usr/lib/R/bin/Rscript' --default-packages=datasets,utils,grDevices,graphics,stats,methods -e 'parallel:::.slaveRSOCK()' MASTER=localhost PORT=11306 OUT= TIMEOUT=2592000 XDR=TRUE
Waiting for worker #1 on ‘localhost’ to connect back
starting worker pid=7608 on localhost:11306 at 14:46:57.827
Connection with worker #1 on ‘localhost’ established
- assigning connection UUID
- collecting session information
Creating node 1 of 1 ... done
```

PS. You only need one worker to troubleshoot this.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Actually I tried this approach obtained similar outputs. "Waiting for worker #1 on ‘localhost’ to connect back
starting worker pid=13731 on localhost:11214 at 15:48:41.991". So I guess it is a connection problem. But I have no idea what these numbers mean ...

Answer (score 0):

After weeks of trying I finally solved this problem. I am putting my answer here.

The problem is actually caused by some unknown firewall issue within the macOS. The solution for this is to **reinstall the entire operating system** ... I know this sounds stupid and troublesome, but the problem is solved after that.

The motivation for doing so is that I happen to notice I do not have access to some of my folders under the home directory (I tried to use `sudo` to modify some files but was not granted access). This is my personal laptop and there is not supposed to have such issue. I then realize that this Mac was synced from my old Mac. The syncing process might cause some firewall issues.