# r parallel::makeCluster() hangs on Mac

Tags: r, macos, parallel-processing

This is somewhat similar to what was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52264460/r-parallel-makecluster-hangs-infinitely-on-mac) but never solved.

I'm moving my first steps in using multiple cores for my R programs, using the `parallel` package. (FYI the application is a maximum likelihood estimator and some bootstrap standard errors.)

When I run the following to enable a cluster using two cores

`cl <- parallel::makeCluster(2)`

R just hangs indefinitely.

Following the question linked above, I try to understand what might be going wrong by running

`cl <- future::makeClusterPSOCK(1, outfile = NULL, verbose = TRUE)`

which gives:

```
Workers: [n = 1] ‘localhost’
Base port: 11662
Creating node 1 of 1 ...
- setting up node
Starting worker #1 on ‘localhost’: '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/Rscript' --default-packages=datasets,utils,grDevices,graphics,stats,methods -e 'parallel:::.slaveRSOCK()' MASTER=localhost PORT=11662 OUT= TIMEOUT=2592000 XDR=TRUE
Waiting for worker #1 on ‘localhost’ to connect back
starting worker pid=89528 on localhost:11662 at 09:36:27.211
Error in socketConnection(master, port = port, blocking = TRUE, open = "a+b",  : 
  cannot open the connection
Calls: <Anonymous> ... doTryCatch -> recvData -> makeSOCKmaster -> socketConnection
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In as.POSIXlt.POSIXct(x, tz) :
  unknown timezone 'zone/tz/2018e.1.0/zoneinfo/Europe/London'
2: In socketConnection(master, port = port, blocking = TRUE, open = "a+b",  :
  localhost:11662 cannot be opened
Execution halted
Error in socketConnection("localhost", port = port, server = TRUE, blocking = TRUE,  : 
  reached elapsed time limit
```

I've tried restarting R, RStudio, my laptop, clearing workspace, etc. but to no avail. Does anyone know what might be going on?

Thanks for your help!

Sessioninfo:

```
R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS High Sierra 10.13.6

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/C/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] compiler_3.4.1      parallel_3.4.1      tools_3.4.1         listenv_0.7.0       yaml_2.2.0         
 [6] optimParallel_0.7-3 codetools_0.2-15    gdata_2.18.0        matrixcalc_1.0-3    digest_0.6.15      
[11] Formula_1.2-3       globals_0.12.3      gtools_3.5.0        future_1.9.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For others who might be experiencing the same problem, what ended up working was adding `192.0.0.1` localhost to my `/etc/hosts` file

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Changing permission in the working directory (recursively) solved it with `chmod -R u+rwx`  solved it.

Comment: Thanks! 

What ended up working was adding
`192.0.0.1 localhost`
to my `/etc/hosts`