# Why are the workers failing to connect when calling `makePSOCKcluster` from an external `R` process?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, cluster-computing, snow

I am experiencing a problem already raised before
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52264460/r-parallel-makecluster-hangs-infinitely-on-mac)
and
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52422201/r-parallelmakecluster-hangs-on-mac),
but in a different context.

Suppose I have an `R` script file called `psock.R` that contains the following
code:

```r
cat("Setup cluster...\n")
cluster <- parallel::makePSOCKcluster(
    rep("localhost", 2),
    master = "localhost",
    port = 11234,
    manual = FALSE,
    outfile = ""
)

cat("Sleep...\n")
Sys.sleep(1)

cat("Teardown cluster...\n")
parallel::stopCluster(cluster)
```

When I run the script via `Rscript --vanilla psock.R`, everything works as
expected, and I see:

```
Setup cluster...
starting worker pid=11557 on localhost:11234 at 13:55:52.818
starting worker pid=11556 on localhost:11234 at 13:55:52.818
Sleep...
Teardown cluster...
```

However, when I try to do the same from within an external `R` process, the
`parallel::makePSOCKcluster` hangs. For example, suppose `psock.R` now contains
the following code instead:

```r
# Create a session.
session <- callr::r_session$new()

cat("Setup cluster...\n")
session$run(function() {
    # Create a cluster in the `.GlobalEnv`.
    cluster <<- parallel::makePSOCKcluster(
        rep("localhost", 2),
        master = "localhost",
        port = 11234,
        manual = FALSE,
        outfile = ""
    )
})

cat("Sleep...\n")
Sys.sleep(5)

cat("Teardown cluster...\n")
session$run(function() {
    # Stop it.
    parallel::stopCluster(cluster)
})

# Close session.
session$close()
```

Running `psock.R` now hangs at `Setup cluster...` for several minutes and then it exits with an error, i.e.:

```
Cluster setup failed. 1 worker of 2 failed to connect.
```

Furthermore, running `htop --filter /exec/R` confirms that the first worker
manages to connect, but the second one doesn't. More specifically, I see the
following processes (i.e., numbers added by me):

```
(1) └─ /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/exec/R --no-echo --no-restore --vanilla --file=psock.R
(2)    └─ /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/exec/R --no-readline --slave --no-save --no-restore
(3) ├─ /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/exec/R --no-echo --no-restore -e tryCatch(parallel:::.workRSOCK,error=function(e)parallel:::.slaveRSOCK)() --args MASTER=localhost PORT=11234 OUT= SETUPTIMEOUT=120 TIMEOUT=2592000 XDR=TRUE SETUPSTRATEGY=parallel
```

where (1) is the `psock.R` script call, (2) is the external process created by
`callr::r_session$new()`, and (3) is the first worker spawned by
`parallel::makePSOCKcluster` that manages to connect.

Following [Steve Weston](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2109128/steve-weston)'s
answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17925618) and
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19259825), I tried to do some debugging.

I started by adjusting `psock.R` to write the output on the external process to
a file and enabling manual mode by setting `manual = TRUE`, i.e.:

```r
session$run(function() {
    # Connection.
    connection <- file("/some/path/log.txt", open = "wt")

    # Write anything to a log file.
    sink(connection, append = TRUE)
    sink(connection, append = TRUE, type = "message")

    # Create a cluster in the `.GlobalEnv`.
    cluster <<- parallel::makePSOCKcluster(
        rep("localhost", 2),
        master = "localhost",
        port = 11234,
        manual = TRUE,
        outfile = ""
    )
})
```

Running `Rscript --vanilla psock.R` after the code change above logs the
following command to `log.txt`:

```
Manually start worker on localhost with
    '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/Rscript' --default-packages=datasets,utils,grDevices,graphics,stats,methods -e 'tryCatch(parallel:::.workRSOCK,error=function(e)parallel:::.slaveRSOCK)()' MASTER=localhost PORT=11234 OUT='' SETUPTIMEOUT=120 TIMEOUT=2592000 XDR=TRUE SETUPSTRATEGY=sequential
```

So far, no workers have been created, as can be seen from the output of `htop --filter /exec/R`:

```
└─ /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/exec/R --no-echo --no-restore --vanilla --file=psock.R
   └─ /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/exec/R --no-readline --slave --no-save --no-restore
```

Now, I can manually run the command above, twice, to create the workers and
connect to the main (i.e., external) process. This results in the following
output in the terminal, confirming that the workers have been created and
connected:

```
starting worker pid=13065 on localhost:11234 at 14:59:38.185
starting worker pid=13201 on localhost:11234 at 14:59:38.185
```

I can also verify this via `htop --filter /exec/R`, which now shows the
following:

```
└─ /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/exec/R --no-echo --no-restore --vanilla --file=psock.R
   └─ /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/exec/R --no-readline --slave --no-save --no-restore
└─ /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/exec/R --no-echo --no-restore -e tryCatch(parallel:::.workRSOCK,error=function(e)parallel:::.slaveRSOCK)() --args MASTER=localhost PORT=11234 OUT= SETUPTIMEOUT=120 TIMEOUT=2592000 XDR=TRUE SETUPSTRATEGY=sequential
└─ /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/exec/R --no-echo --no-restore -e tryCatch(parallel:::.workRSOCK,error=function(e)parallel:::.slaveRSOCK)() --args MASTER=localhost PORT=11234 OUT= SETUPTIMEOUT=120 TIMEOUT=2592000 XDR=TRUE SETUPSTRATEGY=sequential
```

At this point I am confused because I would expect something to fail. The only
explanation I can think of is that the process I created to start the `PSOCK`
cluster behaves differently than manually running that command in the terminal.
Perhaps different permissions or missing environment variables? Is this to be
expected?

I also noticed in the command printed by the manual mode that
`SETUPSTRATEGY=sequential` is used. However, when `manual = FALSE`, the `htop`
process shows that `SETUPSTRATEGY=parallel` is employed. This is, indeed, in
line with the documentation of `parallel::makePSOCKcluster` which reads:

> If "parallel" (default) workers will be started in parallel during cluster
> setup when this is possible, which is now for homogeneous "PSOCK" clusters
> with all workers started automatically (manual = FALSE) on the local machine.
> Workers will be started sequentially on other clusters, on all clusters with
> setup_strategy = "sequential" and on R 3.6.0 and older.

Out of curiosity, I tried running the command printed by the manual model, with
the `parallel` strategy instead (i.e., `SETUPSTRATEGY=parallel`). After
running it only once, the script resumes execution and stops at the
`Sys.sleep(5)` part. This is also reflected in the `htop` process list, where I can only
see one worker.

Everything works as expected if I disable the manual mode and add
`setup_strategy = "sequential"` in the `parallel::makePSOCKcluster` function
call. **However, I really want to know why it fails with a `parallel` setup
strategy.** Furthermore, the code runs fine on a Windows machine, but hangs
just the same on a Debian-based system.

In terms of what I'm running, this is what my `R` session looks like:

```r
sessionInfo()

# R version 4.2.1 (2022-06-23)
# Platform: aarch64-apple-darwin20 (64-bit)
# Running under: macOS Monterey 12.6
#
# Matrix products: default
# BLAS:   /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/lib/libRblas.0.dylib
# LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib
#
# locale:
# [1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8
#
# attached base packages:
# [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
#
# loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
# [1] compiler_4.2.1 cli_3.3.0      jsonlite_1.8.0 rlang_1.0.5
```

And, since other answers have indicated host-related issues, my `/etc/hosts`
looks like:

```
───────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
   1   │ ##
   2   │ # Host Database
   3   │ #
   4   │ # localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
   5   │ # when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
   6   │ ##
   7   │ 127.0.0.1       localhost
   8   │ 255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
   9   │ ::1             localhost
───────┴─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
```

Also, my `.Rprofile` is empty.

Finally, not sure if this is relevant, but when running `netstat -i`, the values
in the `Address` column for my network interfaces are in the format of IPv6, or
rather IPv4-mapped.

Before I succumb to `setup_strategy = "sequential"`, do you have any idea what
is going on?

---

**Edit 1.**

Following [HenrikB](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1072091/henrikb)'s suggestion, I replaced the `parallel::makePSOCKcluster` call with `parallelly::makeClusterPSOCK` and before the call I enabled the debug logs `options(parallelly.debug = TRUE)`. The code now looks like this:

```r
session$run(function() {
    # Enable logging for `parallelly`.
    options(parallelly.debug = TRUE)

    # Connection.
    connection <- file("/some/path/log.txt", open = "wt")

    # Write anything to a log file.
    sink(connection, append = TRUE)
    sink(connection, append = TRUE, type = "message")

    # Create a cluster in the `.GlobalEnv`.
    cluster <<- parallelly::makeClusterPSOCK(
        rep("localhost", 2),
        master = "localhost",
        port = 11234,
        manual = FALSE,
        outfile = ""
    )
})
```

The output in `log.txt` contains the following:

```
[09:27:19.936] Set package option ‘parallelly.availableCores.methods’
[09:27:19.941] Environment variable ‘R_PARALLELLY_AVAILABLECORES_METHODS’ not set
[09:27:19.941] Set package option ‘parallelly.availableCores.fallback’
[09:27:19.941] Environment variable ‘R_PARALLELLY_AVAILABLECORES_FALLBACK’ not set
[09:27:19.941] Set package option ‘parallelly.availableCores.min’
[09:27:19.942] Environment variable ‘R_PARALLELLY_AVAILABLECORES_MIN’ not set
[09:27:19.942] Set package option ‘parallelly.availableCores.system’
[09:27:19.942] Environment variable ‘R_PARALLELLY_AVAILABLECORES_SYSTEM’ not set
[09:27:19.942] Set package option ‘parallelly.availableCores.logical’
[09:27:19.942] Environment variable ‘R_PARALLELLY_AVAILABLECORES_LOGICAL’ not set
[09:27:19.942] Set package option ‘parallelly.availableCores.omit’
[09:27:19.942] Environment variable ‘R_PARALLELLY_AVAILABLECORES_OMIT’ not set
[09:27:19.942] Set package option ‘parallelly.availableWorkers.methods’
[09:27:19.942] Environment variable ‘R_PARALLELLY_AVAILABLEWORKERS_METHODS’ not set
[09:27:19.942] Set package option ‘parallelly.fork.enable’
[09:27:19.942] Environment variable ‘R_PARALLELLY_FORK_ENABLE’ not set
[09:27:19.942] Set package option ‘parallelly.supportsMulticore.unstable’
[09:27:19.942] Environment variable ‘R_PARALLELLY_SUPPORTSMULTICORE_UNSTABLE’ not set
[09:27:19.943] Set package option ‘parallelly.makeNodePSOCK.setup_strategy’
[09:27:19.943] Environment variable ‘R_PARALLELLY_MAKENODEPSOCK_SETUP_STRATEGY’ not set
[09:27:19.943] Set package option ‘parallelly.makeNodePSOCK.validate’
[09:27:19.943] Environment variable ‘R_PARALLELLY_MAKENODEPSOCK_VALIDATE’ not set
[09:27:19.943] Set package option ‘parallelly.makeNodePSOCK.connectTimeout’
[09:27:19.943] Environment variable ‘R_PARALLELLY_MAKENODEPSOCK_CONNECTTIMEOUT’ not set
[09:27:19.943] Set package option ‘parallelly.makeNodePSOCK.timeout’
[09:27:19.943] Environment variable ‘R_PARALLELLY_MAKENODEPSOCK_TIMEOUT’ not set
[09:27:19.943] Set package option ‘parallelly.makeNodePSOCK.useXDR’
[09:27:19.943] Environment variable ‘R_PARALLELLY_MAKENODEPSOCK_USEXDR’ not set
[09:27:19.943] Set package option ‘parallelly.makeNodePSOCK.socketOptions’
[09:27:19.943] Environment variable ‘R_PARALLELLY_MAKENODEPSOCK_SOCKETOPTIONS’ not set
[09:27:19.943] Set package option ‘parallelly.makeNodePSOCK.rshcmd’
[09:27:19.943] Environment variable ‘R_PARALLELLY_MAKENODEPSOCK_RSHCMD’ not set
[09:27:19.944] Set package option ‘parallelly.makeNodePSOCK.rshopts’
[09:27:19.944] Environment variable ‘R_PARALLELLY_MAKENODEPSOCK_RSHOPTS’ not set
[09:27:19.944] Set package option ‘parallelly.makeNodePSOCK.tries’
[09:27:19.944] Environment variable ‘R_PARALLELLY_MAKENODEPSOCK_TRIES’ not set
[09:27:19.944] Set package option ‘parallelly.makeNodePSOCK.tries.delay’
[09:27:19.944] Environment variable ‘R_PARALLELLY_MAKENODEPSOCK_TRIES_DELAY’ not set
[09:27:19.944] Set package option ‘parallelly.makeNodePSOCK.rscript_label’
[09:27:19.944] Environment variable ‘R_PARALLELLY_MAKENODEPSOCK_RSCRIPT_LABEL’ not set
[09:27:19.944] Set package option ‘parallelly.makeNodePSOCK.sessionInfo.pkgs’
[09:27:19.944] Environment variable ‘R_PARALLELLY_MAKENODEPSOCK_SESSIONINFO_PKGS’ not set
[09:27:19.944] Set package option ‘parallelly.makeNodePSOCK.autoKill’
[09:27:19.944] Environment variable ‘R_PARALLELLY_MAKENODEPSOCK_AUTOKILL’ not set
[09:27:19.944] Set package option ‘parallelly.makeNodePSOCK.master.localhost.hostname’
[09:27:19.945] Environment variable ‘R_PARALLELLY_MAKENODEPSOCK_MASTER_LOCALHOST_HOSTNAME’ not set
[09:27:19.945] Set package option ‘parallelly.makeNodePSOCK.port.increment’
[09:27:19.945] Environment variable ‘R_PARALLELLY_MAKENODEPSOCK_PORT_INCREMENT’ not set
[09:27:19.945] parallelly-specific environment variables:
[09:27:19.961] [local output] Workers: [n = 2] ‘localhost’, ‘localhost’
[09:27:19.962] [local output] Base port: 11234
[09:27:19.962] [local output] Getting setup options for 2 cluster nodes ...
[09:27:19.963] [local output]  - Node 1 of 2 ...
[09:27:19.963] [local output] localMachine=TRUE => revtunnel=FALSE

[09:27:19.963] Testing if worker's PID can be inferred: ‘'/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/Rscript' -e 'try(suppressWarnings(cat(Sys.getpid(),file="/var/folders/v9/yftkgjms78qdx9vz7mll88mw0000gn/T//RtmpRVw8vP/worker.rank=1.parallelly.parent=3664.e504deb9152.pid")), silent = TRUE)' -e 'file.exists("/var/folders/v9/yftkgjms78qdx9vz7mll88mw0000gn/T//RtmpRVw8vP/worker.rank=1.parallelly.parent=3664.e504deb9152.pid")'’
[09:27:19.978] - Possible to infer worker's PID: FALSE
[09:27:19.978] [local output] Rscript port: 11234

[09:27:19.978] [local output]  - Node 2 of 2 ...
[09:27:19.979] [local output] localMachine=TRUE => revtunnel=FALSE

[09:27:19.979] Testing if worker's PID can be inferred: ‘'/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/Rscript' -e 'try(suppressWarnings(cat(Sys.getpid(),file="/var/folders/v9/yftkgjms78qdx9vz7mll88mw0000gn/T//RtmpRVw8vP/worker.rank=2.parallelly.parent=3664.e502491c675.pid")), silent = TRUE)' -e 'file.exists("/var/folders/v9/yftkgjms78qdx9vz7mll88mw0000gn/T//RtmpRVw8vP/worker.rank=2.parallelly.parent=3664.e502491c675.pid")'’
[09:27:19.995] - Possible to infer worker's PID: FALSE
[09:27:19.995] [local output] Rscript port: 11234

[09:27:19.995] [local output] Getting setup options for 2 cluster nodes ... done
[09:27:19.995] [local output]  - Parallel setup requested for some PSOCK nodes
[09:27:19.996] [local output] Setting up PSOCK nodes in parallel
[09:27:19.996] List of 20
[09:27:19.996]  $ local_cmd     : chr "'/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/Rscript' --default-packages=datasets,utils,grDevices,graphics,st"| __truncated__
[09:27:19.996]  $ worker        : chr "localhost"
[09:27:19.996]   ..- attr(*, "localhost")= logi TRUE
[09:27:19.996]  $ rank          : int 1
[09:27:19.996]  $ rshlogfile    : NULL
[09:27:19.996]  $ port          : int 11234
[09:27:19.996]  $ connectTimeout: num 120
[09:27:19.996]  $ timeout       : num 2592000
[09:27:19.996]  $ useXDR        : logi FALSE
[09:27:19.996]  $ pidfile       : chr "/var/folders/v9/yftkgjms78qdx9vz7mll88mw0000gn/T//RtmpRVw8vP/worker.rank=1.parallelly.parent=3664.e504deb9152.pid"
[09:27:19.996]  $ setup_strategy: chr "parallel"
[09:27:19.996]  $ outfile       : chr ""
[09:27:19.996]  $ rshcmd_label  : NULL
[09:27:19.996]  $ rsh_call      : NULL
[09:27:19.996]  $ cmd           : chr "'/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/Rscript' --default-packages=datasets,utils,grDevices,graphics,st"| __truncated__
[09:27:19.996]  $ localMachine  : logi TRUE
[09:27:19.996]  $ manual        : logi FALSE
[09:27:19.996]  $ dryrun        : logi FALSE
[09:27:19.996]  $ quiet         : logi FALSE
[09:27:19.996]  $ rshcmd        : NULL
[09:27:19.996]  $ revtunnel     : logi FALSE
[09:27:19.996]  - attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "makeNodePSOCKOptions" "makeNodeOptions"
[09:27:20.001] [local output] System call to launch all workers:
[09:27:20.001] [local output] '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/Rscript' --default-packages=datasets,utils,grDevices,graphics,stats,methods -e 'try(suppressWarnings(cat(Sys.getpid(),file="/var/folders/v9/yftkgjms78qdx9vz7mll88mw0000gn/T//RtmpRVw8vP/worker.rank=1.parallelly.parent=3664.e504deb9152.pid")), silent = TRUE)' -e 'options(socketOptions = "no-delay")' -e 'workRSOCK <- tryCatch(parallel:::.workRSOCK, error=function(e) parallel:::.slaveRSOCK); workRSOCK()' MASTER=localhost PORT=11234 OUT= TIMEOUT=2592000 XDR=FALSE SETUPTIMEOUT=120 SETUPSTRATEGY=parallel
[09:27:20.001] [local output] Starting PSOCK main server
[09:27:20.003] [local output] Workers launched
[09:27:20.003] [local output] Waiting for workers to connect back
[09:27:20.003] [local output] 0 workers out of 2 ready
[09:27:20.120] [local output] 0 workers out of 2 ready
[09:27:20.121] [local output] 1 workers out of 2 ready
[09:29:20.126] [local output] 1 workers out of 2 ready
[09:31:20.133] [local output] 1 workers out of 2 ready
Error in parallelly::makeClusterPSOCK(rep("localhost", 2), master = "localhost",  : 
  Cluster setup failed. 1 worker of 2 failed to connect.
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In system(test_cmd, intern = TRUE, input = input) :
  running command ''/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/Rscript' -e 'try(suppressWarnings(cat(Sys.getpid(),file="/var/folders/v9/yftkgjms78qdx9vz7mll88mw0000gn/T//RtmpRVw8vP/worker.rank=1.parallelly.parent=3664.e504deb9152.pid")), silent = TRUE)' -e 'file.exists("/var/folders/v9/yftkgjms78qdx9vz7mll88mw0000gn/T//RtmpRVw8vP/worker.rank=1.parallelly.parent=3664.e504deb9152.pid")'' had status 2
2: In system(test_cmd, intern = TRUE, input = input) :
  running command ''/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/Rscript' -e 'try(suppressWarnings(cat(Sys.getpid(),file="/var/folders/v9/yftkgjms78qdx9vz7mll88mw0000gn/T//RtmpRVw8vP/worker.rank=2.parallelly.parent=3664.e502491c675.pid")), silent = TRUE)' -e 'file.exists("/var/folders/v9/yftkgjms78qdx9vz7mll88mw0000gn/T//RtmpRVw8vP/worker.rank=2.parallelly.parent=3664.e502491c675.pid")'' had status 2
```

It looks like the `Rscript` command has an exit status of `2`, which from the [documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/quit.html) sounds like something cryptic happened:

> Error status `2` is used for `R` 'suicide', that is a catastrophic failure, and other small numbers are used by specific ports for initialization failures.

Comment: FWIW, it works fine on Ubuntu 20.04 running R version 4.2.1 (2022-06-23) with up-to-date CRAN packages. I've tested via `R --vanilla` and `Rscript --vanilla script.R`.

Comment: To rule out `localhost` being an issue, try using `127.0.0.1` for the worker hostnames.

Comment: Also, try to replace `parallel::makePSOCKcluster()` with `parallelly::makeClusterPSOCK()` as it gives more informative error messages.  You can also set `options(parallelly.debug = TRUE)` to get detailed output on the what's taking place internally.

Comment: @HenrikB, thanks for taking the time. When I use `127.0.0.1` for the worker hostnames (i.e., or both for the workers and the master), no workers are created. With the `localhost` hostname, one gets started, and the other one hangs.
Does this suggest anything to you? I will update in a moment my answer to include the debug logs from `options(parallelly.debug = TRUE)`.

Comment: @HenrikB, I updated my question in line with your recommendation. I am still trying to wrap my head around the logs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE 2022-10-10:
The underlying problem was due to a bug in R itself, which has been fixed in R-devel r83051 (2022-10-10) https://github.com/wch/r-source/commit/97b3dfb71aeff4a6acb72d400bb1fba8e6b2ed37. Not sure, but I suspect this fix will also make it into R v4.2.2 (end of October 2022).

With a fixed version of R, OP's example works also with **processx** 3.7.0 currently on CRAN.

UPDATE 2022-10-09:

The problem is related to the **processx** package and R itself requiring a working standard input (stdin) stream.  Specifically, **callr** (when using **processx** <= 3.7.0) marks all file descriptors as close-on-exec and `system2()` assumes that stdin (etc.) will be inherited in the child process, instead of explicitly duplicating it. This caused `system()` to fail, cf. https://github.com/r-lib/callr/issues/236.  Because of this, the **processx** package (>= 3.7.0-9000) was updated to *not* close the standard streams (stdin, stdout, and stderr) by default.  This solved the problem reported by OP (confirmed by OP on 2022-10-08T21:05:46 UTC).

Until the fixed version of **processx** package is on [CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/package=processx), the developers version can be installed as:

```
remotes::install_github("r-lib/processx")
```

---

Thanks to your updated debug output(*) from `parallelly::makeClusterPSOCK()`, I've narrowed it in to what right now looks like a bug in **callr**.  I've reported this upstream at https://github.com/r-lib/callr/issues/236, which also illustrates the core of the problem.

(*) The exact thing that caught my eye was:

```
[09:27:19.963] Testing if worker's PID can be inferred: ‘'/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/Rscript' -e 'try(suppressWarnings(cat(Sys.getpid(),file="/var/folders/v9/yftkgjms78qdx9vz7mll88mw0000gn/T//RtmpRVw8vP/worker.rank=1.parallelly.parent=3664.e504deb9152.pid")), silent = TRUE)' -e 'file.exists("/var/folders/v9/yftkgjms78qdx9vz7mll88mw0000gn/T//RtmpRVw8vP/worker.rank=1.parallelly.parent=3664.e504deb9152.pid")'’
[09:27:19.978] - Possible to infer worker's PID: FALSE
```

and more precisely, that it failed to infer the worker's PID when called with a background **callr** process.  If you do the same in the main R session, you'll get:

```
[09:27:19.978] - Possible to infer worker's PID: TRUE
```

Comment: This is brilliant! But I am still curious why it fails only on `macOS`? In your previous comment, you indicated it works on `Ubuntu 20.04` and I just checked it again on `Windows`. The command on `Windows` was `"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-42~1.1/bin/x64/Rscript" -e "try(suppressWarnings(cat(Sys.getpid(),file=\"e:/Users/u1276045/AppData/Local/Temp/33/RtmpMR2UEe/worker.rank=1.parallelly.parent=49752.c2586f93547a.pid\")), silent = TRUE)" -e "file.exists(\"e:/Users/u1276045/AppData/Local/Temp/33/RtmpMR2UEe/worker.rank=1.parallelly.parent=49752.c2586f93547a.pid\")"`.

Comment: Yeah, I'm still not 100% sure why it appears to work on Ubuntu, because the simple `Rscript -e ...` test certainly fails there.  To be discovered ...

Comment: Indeed, it puzzles me as well. I will leave the question open for several days in case others have more ideas. Then I’ll accept your answer. Thanks for opening the issue on GitHub!

Comment: Please retry with the devel version of **processx**, i.e. `remotes::install_github("r-lib/processx")`, which fixed the bug I reported on. Let's see if that solved everything.

Comment: It works like a charm! I want to award you a bounty as a token of appreciation for unraveling this obscure bug (i.e., when the waiting period ends). Would you mind editing your answer to clarify in a few words what went wrong? Perhaps others could benefit as well.

Comment: Answer updated.

Comment: For the record, processx does not (and did not) close stdin, etc., that's not what I said in the referenced issue. Closing them would be bad indeed. In fact, quite the opposite, processx makes sure that the new subprocess has a proper stdin etc. open. `system()` does not, otoh.

Comment: Sorry @GaborCsardi, so it's me not understanding. For me to correct this answer, how should "Specifically, processx (<= 3.7.0) closes stdin, together with standard output (stdout) and standard error (stderr), ..." be rewritten?

Comment: Like the top of https://github.com/r-lib/callr/issues/236#issuecomment-1272317912 ?

Comment: "callr (when using processx <= 3.7.0) marks all file descriptors as close-on-exec and system2() assumes that stdin (etc.) will be inherited in the child process, instead of explicitly duplicating it."